# Why does bootstrap carousel get initialized without the data-bs-ride attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap official documentation says:

> If you don’t use data-bs-ride="carousel" to initialize your carousel, you have to initialize it yourself.

Below is an example which **doesn't use** `data-bs-ride="carousel"` or any javascript to initialize the carousel, but still it works, why?

```css
.carousel {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="carouselExampleControls" data-bs-interval="false" class="carousel slide" >
  <div class="carousel-inner" >
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      111
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" >
      222
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" >
      333
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target=".carousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target=".carousel" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>

<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap’s carousel component will [automatically initialize](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/bc1b5b25edbc6657ceab694dbbeb00aed5dca431/js/src/carousel.js#L441) when you click on the buttons of a carousel that isn’t initialized yet. So if you don’t need autoplay, omitting `data-bs-ride="carousel"` will work.

You will need to use `data-bs-ride="carousel"` or [JavaScript code](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/#via-javascript) to make sure that the carousel is initialized on page load if you use autoplay.

Comment: Does `data-bs-ride="false"` also initialize the carousel and at the same time stop autoplay?